# Connection between Expected value and randomized/probabilistic algorithms

Tags: probability, algorithms, expectation, random

Why people often use an expected value notation to tell something about randomized or probabilistic algorithm?

What can expected value tell us about this algorithm? Does this algorithm have a low chance of error or what?

So far, I know that expected value can be used in order to show that particular algorithm belongs to **ZPP** (by definition), but I'm pretty sure that's not the main thing here.

Also, I know that it is possible to prove that QuickSort is $O(n \log n)$ in average case, using expected value notation, so I assume it can help us to find that the time complexity of some randomized/probabilistic algorithm, but only in average case?

Comment: Sometimes how well something performs varies a lot depending on how the input is packaged. Instead of having to consider all possibilities, considering the average can be convenient. Sometimes bounds for worst or best cases are also shown or derived. Which cases are worth looking on depends a lot on the application, what data the algorithm can expect to be seeing and how it will be packaged.

Comment: For example sorting 1,2,3,4,5,6 would in worst case require lots of comparisons for an algorithm, but another algorithm might see straight away that it is already sorted, but it could be that the second algorithm performs worse on large data sets that are really shuffled.

The expected time is a way to try and get a measure of the performance regardless of how the data it will handle is packaged.